# What are some other ways to find the joint distribution of $(X,S)$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions, random-variables, binomial-distribution

let $X, Y$ be two independant random variables such that : $X \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathscr{Bernoulli(p)}$ and $Y \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathscr{Binomial(n,p)}$

let $S = X + Y$ then $S \stackrel{}{\sim} \mathscr{Binomial(n+1,p)}$

how do do you find the joint distribution of $(X,S) ?$

here's a try (check if there's no mistakes) :

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X=x,S=s) & = \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=s-x)\\
&= \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y) \; \color{red}{\text{is this step correct ?}} \\
& = \mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y) \; \color{red}{\text{because they're independant}}\\
&= p^x(1-p)^{1-x} {{n}\choose{y}}p^{y}(1-p)^{n-y} \\
&=p^x(1-p)^{1-x} {{n}\choose{s-x}}p^{s-x}(1-p)^{n-s+x} \\
&= {{n}\choose{s-x}}p^{s}(1-p)^{n-s+1}
\end{align}$$

I'm also interested in other methods of solving this.

any comments or hints will be appreciated.

EDIT : basically what's bothering me the most is the equality  : $\mathbb{P}(X=x,S=s) = \mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$

Comment: You do not need to change to the dummy variable $y$ before you apply the properties - line 2-4 can be replaced by single step $\Pr\{X = x\}\Pr\{Y = s-x\}$ following the first line. You may consider to write one more like $\Pr\{X = x, S = s\} = \Pr\{X = x, X+Y = s\}$ if that bother you. The results looks good, but in specifying a joint pmf (or pdf) you better state the support.

Comment: You are just writing $y$ for $s-x$ in the second line. It requires no justification. Your argument is correct. It is natural and simple. Why do you want other ways of finding the joint distribution?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I too tought it was natural but my teacher didn't like that step and couldn't say if it was wrong or correct even though her weird method which consists of computing $\mathbb{E}[h(X,S)]$ and then use identification is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you question are quite correct.   You are temporarily substituting $y= s-x$, which is quite okay, and indeed the independence of $X,Y$ does mean you can use the product rule.

However, please don't forget to indicate the support for the joint probability mass function.$$(X,S)\in\{(x,s): x\in\{0,1\}, s\in\{x, x+1,...,n+x\}\}$$

---

An alternative approach from first principles:  $S$ is the count of successes among $n+1$ independent and identically distributed Bernoulli trials (with success rate $p$), and $X$ the indicator that the last trial is a success.  So $\{X=x,S=s\}$ is the event of $s-x$ successes among the first $n$ trials, and $x$ successes among the last; giving $n+1-s$ failures among the $n+1$ trials.   Noting that $x\in\{0,1\}$ and $s-x\in\{0,...,n\}$ then we have:$$\mathsf P(X=x,S=s)=\binom{n}{s-x}p^s(1-p)^{n+1-s}\mathbf 1_{x\in\{0,1\},s-x\in\{0,...,n\}}$$

Comment: oh, yes the support is important. which is $(x,s) \in \{0,1\}\times\{0,1,\dots,n+1\}$. thanks !

Comment: No, it is: $(X,S)\in\{(x,s): x\in\{0,1\}, s\in\{x, x+1,...,n+x\}\}$